# convergence series geometric test

Tags: convergence-divergence

Prove if this converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n+3}{3^n-1}$$

pf: using geometric

$$0 < \frac{2^n+3}{3^n-1} \leq \frac{2^n + 2 \times 2^n}{3^n-\frac{3^n}{2}} = \cdots $$ and so on

I know how to do the rest but my question is that where in the world did my teacher get

$$\frac{2^n + 2 \times 2^n}{3^n-\frac{3^n}{2}}$$

Comment: The ratio test does it.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better bound would be
$$\frac{2^n+3}{3^n-1}=\frac{2^n(1+3\cdot 2^{-n})}{3^n(1-3^{-n})}\leq \frac{5/2}{2/3}\frac{2^n}{3^n}$$

Comment: OP's bound gives convergence ($\frac{2^n+2\cdot 2^n}{3^n-3^n/2}= \frac{6\cdot 2^n}{3^n}$).

Comment: @Milly You're right. Let me edit.

Answer (score 0):

You teacher increased the numerator (from $2^n+3$ to $2^n+ 2\cdot 2^n$, since $3\leq 2\cdot 2^n$), and decreased the denominator (from $3^n-1$ to $3^n-3^n/2$, since $1<3^n/2$), thus obtains a fraction (i.e. $\frac{2^n+2\cdot 2^n}{3^n-3^n/2}$) which is bigger than the original (i.e. $\frac{2^n+3}{3^n-1}$).

Answer (score 0):

Ratio test:
$$
\frac{\left(\dfrac{2^{n+1}+3}{3^{n+1}-1}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{2^n+3}{3^n-1}\right)} \to \frac 2 3 \text{ as }n\to\infty,
$$
so the series converges.